# Not able to add image to PDF using jspdf in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jspdf

I am using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate PDF file using JavaScript. In my PDF file I am adding images. I am able to generate PDF in Chrome and Firefox, but adding image to PDF creates security error in IE11.

[image]

**JS Code:**

```
(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.setFont("courier");
    doc.setFontType("bolditalic");
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.text(105, 15, 'IE 11 PDF Image Insert Test', null, null, 'center');    

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        console.log('img onload');
        doc.addImage(img, 'png', 24, 63, 80, 80);
        doc.save('ie11_test.pdf');
    };
    img.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/images/storelocator_clothing.png';
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
})();
```

How fix this image insert issue with IE11?

Comment: Maybe it's because the image is in a different origin? Try serving your image from the same origin jsPDF runs on.

Comment: I am going to pull images from different origins only (google maps api), so need solution which works cross origin.

Comment: Lets first verify that it is indeed the cause. Try same origin and see if it works in IE11. If that's indeed the issue then you can set up a proxy to serve other origins from your own.

Comment: Yes, same origin image files are working in IE 11

Comment: did you find a solution? did you use a proxy?